# Opensearch - parse the log in Kibana and extract the values with alias names

Tags: kibana

Since I am quite new to Kibana I couldn't understand how to parse my log in the console. Currently I am not looking parsing at index or ingestion pipeline I would like to do it in the console. How can I do this?

[image]

Example log:

`18.68.54.15:57504 [15/Mar/2024:11:28:48.636] someapigetway~ containername- 0/0/0/2/2 401 177 - - ---- 43/40/5/0/0 0/0 "url"`

I need to extract status code here and also url.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.